# updateアクションでデータの更新がされません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

updateアクションの値が変更されなく、エラーは出ておりません。
createは正常に動きます。

### ソースコード

views/searches/edit.html.erb

```
 <%= form_with(model: @search,  local: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :postal_code,"郵便番号" %>
      <%= f.text_field :postal_code, class: "search_form" %>
      <%= f.label :address1,"都道府県" %>
      <%= f.text_field :address1, class: "search_form" %>
      <%= f.label :address2,"市区町村" %>
      <%= f.text_field :address2, class: "search_form" %>
      <%= f.label :address3,"町域" %>
      <%= f.text_field :address3, class: "search_form" %>
      <%= f.label :building_name,"建物名" %>
      <%= f.text_field :building_name, class: "search_form" %>
      <%= f.label :phone_number,"電話番号" %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: "search_form" %>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit class: "button is-warning"%>
    <% end %>
```

controllers/searches_controller.rb

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @search = Search.all
  end

  def edit
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update    
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])    
    @search.update(search_params) 
    redirect_to root_path
  end


  def create
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
    @search.user_id = current_user.id
    @search.save!
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def search
    if postal_code = params[:postal_code]
      params = URI.encode_www_form({zipcode: postal_code})
      uri = URI.parse("http://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?#{params}")
      response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
      result = JSON.parse(response.body)
      if result["results"]
        @zipcode = result["results"][0]["zipcode"]
        @address1 = result["results"][0]["address1"]
        @address2 = result["results"][0]["address2"]
        @address3 = result["results"][0]["address3"]
      end
    end
  end
end

private
 def search_params
  params.permit(:address1, :address2, :address3, :building_name,:phone_number, :postal_code)
 end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'searches',to: "searches#search"
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
   omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
   registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  get 'homes/index'
  resources :homes, only: [:index]
  root to: 'home#index'
  resources :users 
  resources :attendances
  resources :daytimes
  resources :restaurants, only: [:index, :show] 
  resources :searches do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
  namespace :admin do
    resources :restaurants, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show,  :edit, :destroy]
  end
end
```

#### 試したこと

updateアクションでbinding.pryをかけました

```
[2] pry(#<SearchesController>)> Search.find(params[:id])
CACHE Search Load (0.0ms)  SELECT searches.* FROM searches WHERE searches.id = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ (pry):15:in `update'
=> #<Search:0x00007fd6cf3153f0
id: 1,
user_id: 3,
postal_code: "5420076",
address1: "大阪府",
address2: "大阪市中央区",
address3: "難波 5 -1 -60",
building_name: "なんば　スカイオ　15階",
phone_number: "0503187-577",
created_at: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 11:19:35 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 11:19:35 JST +09:00>
[3] pry(#<SearchesController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"3C+utl44ydMFKy+o6uNfUVLEaegW9ryjuvwGKyhzN3jxAk8ZNJift1NaFmvrxWfYdhoeWpVxcMeZJJ1nvI2oHw==", "search"=>{"postal_code"=>"5420076", "address1"=>"大阪府", "address2"=>"大阪市中央区", "address3"=>"難波 5 -1 -60", "building_name"=>"イオ　15階", "phone_number"=>"0503187-577"}, "commit"=>"更新する", "controller"=>"searches", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

```
params.require(:search).permit(:address1, :address2, :address3, :building_name,:phone_number, :postal_code)
```

とコントローラーに.require(:search)を記述したら、updateはされずcreateで、エラーが出ます。

```
ctionController::ParameterMissing in SearchesController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: search
Request
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"search",
"authenticity_token"=>"DiSrEfma6Y5g7xKmfPCILZwDQEz49fHKc76kmo+VKgg+9gxGwH6yWbfNR2im17YrNuSQ8eB+nWqGyIX/jM6OIw==",
"postal_code"=>"5420076",
"address1"=>"大阪府",
"address2"=>"大阪市中央区",
"address3"=>"難波",
"building_name"=>"なんば",
"phone_number"=>"090-1234-5678",
"commit"=>"保存する"}
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/300456) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 1):

update用のストロングパラメータを設定したらupdateできました。

```
def update_params
  params.require(:search).permit(:address1, :address2, :address3, :building_name,:phone_number, :postal_code)
end
```